# Comparing all data to the data of specifically selected user ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table that holds data for team games.

**Objective**:
Count the number of times other `SquadID`'s have have shared the same `Team` value as `SquadID=21`

```
// Selections table
+--------+---------+------+
| GameID | SquadID | Team |
+--------+---------+------+
|      1 |       5 | A    |
|      1 |       7 | B    |
|      1 |      11 | A    |
|      1 |      21 | A    |
|      2 |       5 | A    |
|      2 |       7 | B    |
|      2 |      11 | A    |
|      2 |      21 | A    |
|      3 |       5 | A    |
|      3 |       7 | B    |
|      3 |      11 | A    |
|      3 |      21 | A    |
|      4 |       5 | A    |
|      4 |      11 | B    |
|      4 |      21 | A    |
|      5 |       5 | A    |
|      5 |      11 | B    |
|      5 |      21 | A    |
|      6 |       5 | A    |
|      6 |      11 | B    |
|      6 |      21 | A    |
+--------+---------+------+


// Desired Result
+---------+----------+
| SquadID | TeamMate |
+---------+----------+
|       5 |        6 |
|       7 |        0 |
|      11 |        3 |
|      21 |        6 |
+----------+---------+
```

I've attempted to use a subquery specifying the specific player I wish to compare with and because this subquery has multiple rows, I've used `in` instead of `=`.

```
// Current Query
SELECT
    SquadID, 
    COUNT(Team IN (SELECT Team FROM selections WHERE SquadID=21) AND GameID IN (SELECT GameID FROM selections WHERE SquadID=21)) AS TeamMate 
FROM      
    selections  
GROUP BY 
    SquadID;
```

The result I'm getting is the number of Games a user has played rather than the number of games a user has been on the same team as `SquadID=21`

```
// Current Result
+---------+----------+
| SquadID | TeamMate |
+---------+----------+
|       5 |        6 |
|       7 |        3 |
|      11 |        6 |
|      21 |        6 |
+---------+----------+
```

What am I missing?

---

```
// DESCRIBE selections;
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| GameID  | int(11) | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| SquadID | int(4)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Team    | char(1) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| TeamID  | int(11) | NO   |     | 1       |       |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Your data model or perhaps phrasing is quite confusing. "My objective is to count the number of times other players have been on the same team as a specific player."  If you are counting times players are involved, why is everything in squadID?   Can I assume one squadID is one player?

Comment: Ok, I've ammended it hope that's clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General rule is to avoid nested selects and look for a better way of logically arranging joins.  Lets look at a cross join:

```
From  selections s1
inner join selects s2 on s1.gameid = s2.gameid and s1.team = s2.team
```

This will produce a cross joined list of each squadID that participated with another squadID (IE: they were in the same game and on same team).  We are only interested in the times where the squad participated with squad 21, so add a where clause:

```
where s2.squadid = 21
```

Then it's simply choosing the field/count you want:

```
select s1.squad, count(1) as teammate
```

any aggregate needs a group by

```
group by s1.squad
```

Combine it together and give a go.  Oddly, this will produce a list where squad 21 will be showing as playing on it's own team all 6 times.  Adding a where clause can eliminate this

```
where s1.squadid <> s2.squadid
```

Comment: This works well when measuring how many times players have played together, but If I wanted to list both together and separately in the same joined table am I correct in that I'll need to use nested queries?

Comment: Honestly I don't think there is a time where you can't express it in a different form.  The cross join creates a list of every squad that played on the same team as another squad (game 1 produces 5 - 5, 5 - 11, 5 - 21, 11-5, 11-11, 11-21, 21-5, 21-11, 21-21 for team a and 7-7 for team b).  How you want to read from there is really up to you.  If you remove the s1.team = s2.team condition, you will also get a list of opposing teams in there (when s1.team <> s2.team then opposite sides).  Use case statements to read from as needed

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SquadID, count(t1.team) as TeamMate 
FROM selections as t1 join
   (select distinct  team, gameid from selections where SquadID=21) as t2
   on t1.Team=t2.Team and t1.Gameid=t2.Gameid
GROUP BY SquadID
```